# Need help coping web page to file and then, later, comparing the file to the web page to determine if changes occurred

Tags: python-3.7

**Objective**: In Python 3.7, I want to copy a web page to a file then, periodically I want to compare that file (copied web page) to the actual web page to see if there are any changes.

My code that creates the web page copy (SEC_old.txt) works. When I open this file via notebook++, it displays a perfectly formatted HTML web page. The Notepad++ "Encoding" tap lists the file as "Encode in UTF-8". Here my code below:

```
# CopySEC.py
import urllib.request
import pickle
## Read web page contents into webPageCopy variable.
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001072379&owner=include&count=40'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webPageCopy = response.read()
## Initiate the output file and write the contents of
## webPageCopy variable to the output file.
SEC_copy_bytes = open("SEC_old.txt","wb")
SEC_copy_bytes.write(webPageCopy)
```

Next is my simple program, Compare_SEC, that (1) copies a webpage to a variable (like the above example), (2) opens and reads the Sec_old.txt (web page copy) into another variable and (3) compares the two to determine if any changes have occurred. This program doesn't appear to work. **The Problem:** The program doesn't evaluate the two variables as equal. They should be. Also, I can print the webPageCopy varialble (using Print()) but when I try to do the same with the copy variable (i.e. print(SEC_copy) ), I get the error: **<_io.BufferedReader name='SEC_old.txt'>** and the contents are not printed.

Here's the code to the compare proram:

```
# Compare_SEC.py
import urllib.request
import pickle
## Read web page contents into webPageCopy variable.
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001072379&owner=include&count=40'

#Place SEC website in variable, webPageCopy and print it to console
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webPageCopy = response.read()
print(webPageCopy)

#open file and write contents (old web page) to variable, SEC-copy and print SEC-copy to console
SEC_copy = open("SEC_old.txt","rb")
print(SEC_copy)

#compare variables containing the old copy of the webpage (SEC-copy) to the current web page (webPageCopy) for differneces
if (webPageCopy) != SEC_copy:
    mesg="SEC website not equal to old copy! New SEC filings!!!!!!!"
else:
    mesg="SEC website is equal to old copy.  No new SEC filings"
print(mesg)
```

Here is the output (minus the printing of the webpage) of the results:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='SEC_old.txt'>
SEC website not equal to old copy! New SEC filings!!!!!!!
```

Any help with resolving the problem would be appreciative. Again, here's **The Problem:** The program doesn't evaluate the two variables, SEC_copy and webPageCopy, as equal. They should be. Also, I can print the webPageCopy varialble (using Print()) but when I try to do the same with the copy variable (i.e. print(SEC_copy) ), I get the error: **<_io.BufferedReader name='SEC_old.txt'>** and the contents are not printed.

Thanks in advance. I hope I spelled the issue out clearly.

To further explore resolving this issue, I created a program to simply read the

```
file into two different variables and compare the variables. There were not equivalent! Why?!?!?!?!?  Here's the code:

# Readfile.py
import urllib.request
import pickle

SEC_copy = open("SEC_old3.txt","rb")
SEC_copy2 = open("SEC_old3.txt","rb")

if SEC_copy != SEC_copy2:
    print("files are not equivalent")
else:
    print("files are equal")
```

And here's the output:

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Office/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/readfile.py 
files are not equivalent
```

So, why are the two variables not equal when they should have the same contents?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a work-around.  I rewrote my program to write the new web page to a file (just like the copy). Then I used another method to read both of them. 
It worked. Of course I had to write the current web page to a file and read it again (which is redundant...but I couldn't compare the file with the current web page contents unless I wrote it a file and read it again). Here;s the code:

```
# SEC_CHK.py
import urllib.request
import pickle
import datetime
import calendar
now = (datetime.datetime.now())
activity_msg="Default Message"
programdesc="SEC Check"
programname="SEC_CHK.py"

## Read web page contents into webPageCopy variable.
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001072379&owner=include&count=40'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webPageCopy = response.read()

## write the new web page contents to the output file, SEC_new.txt.
SEC_new = open("SEC_new.txt","wb")
SEC_new.write(webPageCopy)
SEC_new.close

#open new web page file and read contents to variable, SEC_new.
f = open("SEC_new.txt","r")
SEC_new = f.read()
##print(SEC_new)
f.close

#open old web page file and read contents to variable, SEC-old.
g = open("SEC_old.txt","r")
SEC_old = g.read()
##print(SEC_old)
g.close

#compare variables containing the old copy of the webpage (SEC-old) to the current web page (SEC_new) for differneces
logfile = open("prlog.txt","a")
if (SEC_new) != SEC_old:
   activity_msg="!!!!!!!!!New NWBO SEC Filing(s) Found!!!!!!!"
   SEC_old = open("SEC_old.txt","wb")
   SEC_old.write(webPageCopy)
   SEC_old.close
   logfile.write(todaysdate + " @ " + "SEC CHECK  " + timestamp + ":   " + "Old SEC file updated." "\n") 
else:
   activity_msg="SEC website is equal to old copy. No new SEC filings"
print(activity_msg)
logfile = open("prlog.txt","a")
logfile.write(programdesc + "(" + programname + "): " + activity_msg + "\n")
logfile.close()
```